# Favicon.ico not showing in the tab in asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, favicon

This is the code i call in `_Layout.cshtml` :

```
<head>
<link rel="icon" runat="server" href=@Url.Action("~/myicon.ico")  type="image/ico" /> 
</head>
```

But icon don't show . I only get this default icon

[favicon.ico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59lgu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want Url.Content, not Url.Action

```
<link rel="icon" runat="server" href=@Url.Content("~/myicon.ico")  type="image/ico" />
```

Url.Content resolves the path and returns the URL. Url.Action is used when you actually want to call a controller action and do something with the result.